# When I set the default shell, it doesn't "take"

Tags: linux, bash

I want my default shell to be bash. However, whenever I log into my server, the shell is apparently `-bash`:

```
$ echo $0
-bash
```

If I run `bash`, I'm of course switched to bash for that session, but it doesn't stick, even if I do `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Is there some step that I'm missing if I want bash to be my default shell?

Answer (score 6):

After bash runs, it prepends its name with `-` to indicate that it's a login shell.

The `SHELL` variable will contain the path to the actual binary.

Answer (score 2):

You are running `bash`. Try `echo $BASH`, which will point to the binary executed.

Comment: `echo $BASH` gives me `/bin/bash`. If I'm running `bash`, why isn't my `.bashrc` loaded until I actually type `bash`?

Comment: Okay. Could you please help me understand exactly what I need to ask? You understand my overall problem, right? I log in and things are not how I want them to be. I type `bash` and the problem goes away, but I don't want to have to run `bash` every time I log in.

Comment: @JasonSwett: Check the bash man page. It says explicitly that a login shell does not read .bashrc. Read the 'INVOCATION' section.

Comment: Okay. My goal is to get my shell to behave the same as every other shell I've used in my life, i.e. my .bashrc is loaded and colors are turned on. Is it more complicated to achieve this than I understand?

Answer (score 0):

The `-bash` indicates that you're running bash as your login shell.

If you run `/bin/bash` from the login shell and run `echo $0`, then you're seeing the currently running command that was executed from the login shell (but not the login shell itself).

Long story short, you're running bash as your login shell.  You can check your designated login shell by looking for your username in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance logging into a system that gets its user names over NIS? In that case you need to use `ypchsh` to change your login shell info on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Jason,

From your comments at SvenW's answer,
your actual problem seems a bit different to how you describe it in your question.

Why don't you edit your question? :-)

In the mean while you could have a look at [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically), it seems to address your problem. In particular you could add

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to the file `.bash_profile` in your home directory
(or create it, if it does not exist).